How to inject instrumentation only in a specific namespace in kubernetes
kubernetes I have installed operator and required cert to monitor nodejs application. But my nodejs application is running in a different namespace. Running instrumentation in the same namespace also works but should not be configured that way.
So I put the condition that only a specific namespace should be injected in the instrumentation yaml file. If i execute the yaml file, I got an error that the instrumentation is not created.
Below is the yaml file I used.
instrumentation.yaml
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: Instrumentation
metadata:
  name: demo-instrumentation
spec:
  targetNamespaces:
    - nodejsmango 
  exporter:
    endpoint: http://192.168.1.9:4317
  propagators:
    - tracecontext
    - baggage
  sampler:
    type: parentbased_traceidratio
    argument: "1"

Error:
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "instrumentation.yaml": Instrumentation in version "v1alpha1" cannot be handled as a Instrumentation: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.targetNamespaces"

